# Android OpenCV port C++ to Java

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv

I wrote a program using OpenCV in C / C ++.
Now I would like to move it to the Android platform.
I have a problem with this piece of code

```
Mat picture;
vector<Rect> limitsRectangle;
vector<Rect> tableRectangle;
vector<pair<float, float> > x;
void search()
{
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours(picture, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0,0));
    limitsRectangle.clear();
    limitsRectangle.resize( contours.size() );
    vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly( contours.size() );
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < contours.size() ; i++)
    {
        approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 100, true );
        limitsRectangle[i] = boundingRect( Mat(contours_poly[i]) );
    }
    float lb=3.84;
    float ub=6.87;
    tableRectangle.clear();
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i< limitsRectangle.size(); i++ )
    {
        float proportions = ((float)limitsRectangle[i].width/(float)limitsRectangle[i].height);
        if( (proportions > lb) && (proportions < ub))
        {
            limitsRectangle[i].x += 8;
            limitsRectangle[i].y += 0;
            limitsRectangle[i].width *= 0.95;
            limitsRectangle[i].height *= 0.9;
            tableRectangle.push_back(limitsRectangle[i]);
        }}}
```

Below are pieces of code that I managed to change it. I do not know how well I'm doing, so I ask for support and help

```
Mat picture;
List<MatOfRect> limitRectangles = new ArrayList<MatOfRect>();
List<MatOfRect> tableRectangle = new ArrayList<MatOfRect>();
// vector<pair<float, float> > x; ???
void search()
{

    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    Mat hierarchy;
    Imgproc.findContours(resultMat, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, new Point(0, 0));
    limitsRectangle.clear();
    // limitsRectangle.resize ??? no resize in Java

    List<MatOfPoint> contours_poly = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    // contours_poly( contours.size() ); ??? don't work

    for(int i = 0; i < contours.size() ; i++)
    {
        // Imgproc.approxPolyDP(contours[i], contours_poly[i], 100, true); ??? dont work
        // limitRectangles[i] = Imgproc.boundingRect(Mat(contours_poly[i])); ??? dont work
    }
    double lb=3.84;
    double ub=6.87;
    tableRectangle.clear();
```

Comment: There's no such language as C/C++. C doesn't have `vector`; this can only be C++.

Comment: You can tell how well you're doing by whether the new code matches the behavior of the old code.  Are you having problems getting that to happen?

Comment: I would like to get similar behavior code. I do not know how to do it. Therefore, please help. I would like to avoid using the NDK and native code. I'd like to get just through the OpenCV library for Java.

Answer (score 0):

@phoenix37, Have you been able to get your Java code working? I have been trying to adapt some C++ code into my Android project with some success. I believe(in Java) you need to convert your Array List into an Array to be able to access each element. I know this is true for integer array lists. [Here are some Java constructors](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/MatOfPoint.html) for working with OpenCV specific to MatOfPoint. I am still trying to figure these out myself as I am fairly new to Java and OpenCV. I know this doesn't answer your question but hopefully leads you down the right path.